# How to customize login error in django-rest_framework-knox LoginView

Tags: django-rest-framework

0

I'm building user authentication in Django using the built-in user model and knox token authentication. I am trying to create login API with custom login fail message.
This is my code:

```
class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)
```

Here is the Error message that is created by this code

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

I want this error looks like below

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ],
    "code":[ error code]


}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView
from rest_framework import permissions, generics

class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)
```

and in postman headers section Token='Token'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).